# Is it a good idea to use useRef to prevent rerendering on every input change?

Tags: reactjs

I joined a Frontend bootcamp and now I have to create a registration form as a part of my first project. I want to use the best practices to be... you know... one of the best students to get hired afterwards.

The registration form has 9 fields including selcet, textareas and usual inputs. And AFAIK every key press inside any of the inputs will cause the whole component rerender because it will change the state of the component. And I think it's not good in terms of performance.

I'm new to React but I think it would be better if I use useRef on textareas and inputs so I won't change the state on every key press. Textareas expect large amount of text in it. So typing for example 400 symbols will cause 400 rerenders. If I need any input data validation or warning (I don't need any for this project actually) I can use the blur event or form submit event.

And then I want to send the form data on "submit" button click.

So is it a good idea? Isn't using so many (9) refs a bad practice? Also is it a good idea to mix useState data (for select, for example) with useRef data (for textareas) to create one form data object? Or it's better to use only one of the hook (either useRef or useState for all form fields)?

P.S. I can't use useMemo because we haven't learn it yet on the bootcamp. Only useState and useRef.

Comment: No, you should refactor the inputs into their own components instead, so that only the inputs are rerendered and not the whole thing

Comment: @catgirlkelly how do I collect data from all input-components into one form data object without useState then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ref together with a formData.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const form = new FormData(formRef.current)
  const formFields = Object.fromEntries(form)

  Object.entries(formFields).forEach(([fieldName, value]) => // do something

  // get the value of email input field 
  form.get('email')
}

<form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

This way you don't need to update the state every time when onChange fires.
Read more about formData here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: idk why but it doesn't work :( the result of new FormData is just an empty object. But when I console.log the formRef.current I can see that it has keys and values according to the form fields

Comment: There are multiple ways you access form fields data. You can do something like: Object.fromEntries(form)

Comment: thanks a lot! Now it works!! btw it's FormData, not formData :) and why do people usually utilize useState and not this solution? Your solution is much cheaper in terms of performance

Comment: There might be cases where you want to have a full controll of the form element value, but in most cases it's enough to use FormData.

Comment: yes, it's reasonable.. but I read a ton of articles on forms in React. And I never seen anyone using useRef hook. Everyone just always use useState, not matter if they need full control  over the form or not. Why no one think of performance? Dilettantes?

Comment: Sure, but also it's also might be easier to control the form using useState. It really depends on the situation :) If you have a login page, with 2 input fields and one submit button, it really doesn't meter which approach to use...

Comment: okay! Thank you very much again!! I hope my tutor is not a dilettante and won't tell me that using useRef like this is wrong and useState is the best choice for every situation :D